# TableView, how to use array variables to populate data

Tags: tableview, javafx-8

I have a program where I can add Rows and Columns to table, and they are filled with data. Also user can modify cells by clicking it. The problem is that whenever he changes the value of one cell, whole row changes to the same value. I want each cell to have its own independent value(also for new added columns).

```
public class TableData {
public int digitCell;
public static int numberOfColumns = 0;

public TableData(int digit) {   
    this.digitCell = digit;
}

public int getDigitCell() {
    return digitCell;
}

public void setDigitCell(int digit) {
    this.digitCell = digit;
}

//this method creates and return new column and is used whenever the user clicks add new column
public static TableColumn<TableData, Integer> addNewColumn(TableView<?> table){
    int columnWidth = 10;

    TableColumn<TableData, Integer> newColumn = new TableColumn<>("#" + String.valueOf(numberOfColumns));

    newColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<TableData, Integer>forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
    //Callback<TableColumn<TableData, Integer>, TableCell<TableData,Integer>> cellCallback = (TableColumn<DataModel,Integer> p) -> new NowaKlasa();  

    newColumn.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<TableData,Integer>>() {    
        @Override
        public void handle(CellEditEvent<TableData, Integer> event) {
            ((TableData) event.getTableView().getItems(). get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())).  setDigitCell(event.getNewValue());  
        }
    });

    newColumn.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().divide(100/columnWidth));
    newColumn.setMinWidth(25);
    newColumn.setMaxWidth(50);

    newColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<TableData, Integer>("digitCell"));
    ++numberOfColumns;
    return newColumn;
}

}
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

private BorderPane root;
private Button buttAddColumn;
private Button buttDeleteColumn;
private Button buttAddRow;
private Button buttDeleteRow;
private TableView<TableData> tableView;
private HBox hBox;

private ObservableList<TableData> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(/*dodamy tutaj dane kiedy uzytkownik doda nowy rząd*/);

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void init() {
    root = new BorderPane(); 

    //buttony..................
    buttAddColumn = new Button("Dodaj kolumnę");
    buttAddColumn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            buttAddColumnAction(event);
        }
    });
    buttDeleteColumn = new Button("Usuń kolumnę");
    buttDeleteColumn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            buttDeleteColumnAction(event);
        }
    });
    buttAddRow = new Button("Dodaj wiersz");
    buttAddRow.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            buttAddRowAction(event);
        }
    });
    buttDeleteRow = new Button("Usuń wiersz");
    buttDeleteRow.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            buttDeleteRowAction(event);
        }
    });
    //koniec buttonow................

    hBox = new HBox();
    tableView = new TableView<TableData>();

    hBox.getChildren().addAll(buttAddColumn, buttAddRow, buttDeleteColumn, buttDeleteRow);
    tableView.setItems(dataList);
    tableView.setPlaceholder(new Label("Click button to add new columns."));
    tableView.setEditable(true);

    root.setCenter(tableView);
    root.setBottom(hBox);
}


private void buttAddRowAction(ActionEvent event) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    dataList.add(new TableData(rand.nextInt(10)));
}
private void buttDeleteRowAction(ActionEvent event) {
    dataList.remove(dataList.size()-1);

}
private void buttAddColumnAction(ActionEvent event) {
    tableView.getColumns().add(TableData.addNewColumn(tableView));
}
private void buttDeleteColumnAction(ActionEvent event) {
    tableView.getColumns().remove(TableData.numberOfColumns -1);
    TableData.numberOfColumns--;
}
```

}

I think the problem is, if I want to have each cell value stored then I need in data class as many variables as there is cells in row. However I dont know how to reimplement program to do something like that. ?????

Comment: which error exactly?

Comment: see the edited version.

Comment: I don't really understand how your code is supposed to work. Each item in the table view's items list is supposed to represent an entire row, but it seems that each `TableData` object, while it defines an `ArrayList<Integer>` only seems to try to store a single value. Moreover, if `numberOfColumns` is non-zero when you create a `TableData` object, you first create an empty array list (length 0) but then try to set the element at position `numberOfColumns`, which will give an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395016/how-can-i-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-javafx-8-tableview help at all?

Comment: Ive changed question completely. I hope now is more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it!

In this program, user can add rows and columns and each cell will has its own variable. When user adds new column, program dynamically creates another variables(in array) to each data object and stores value from this cell. So changing one cell, doesnt have effect to any other cell... :)

```
public class MyTable extends Application {
private BorderPane root;
private HBox hBox;
private TableView<MyData> tableView;    
private Button buttAddColumn, buttDeleteColumn;
private Button buttAddRow, buttDeleteRow;
private int numberOfColumns = 0;
private ObservableList<MyData> dataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    root = new BorderPane();
    hBox = new HBox();
    buttAddColumn = new Button("Add columns");
    buttDeleteColumn = new Button("Delete columns");
    buttAddRow = new Button("Add rows");
    buttDeleteRow = new Button("Delete rows");
    tableView = new TableView<>();

    tableView.setEditable(true);
    tableView.setItems(dataList);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(buttAddColumn,buttDeleteColumn,buttAddRow,buttDeleteRow);

    root.setTop(hBox);
    root.setCenter(tableView);


    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    buttAddColumn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            buttAddColumnAction(event);
        }
    });
    buttDeleteColumn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            buttDeleteColumnAction(event);
        }
    });
    buttAddRow.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            buttAddRowAction(event);
        }
    });
    buttDeleteRow.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            buttDeleteRowAction(event);
        }
    });
}

private void buttAddColumnAction(ActionEvent event){        
    int i = numberOfColumns;// thats the key for lambda expression. Unique number for each column to access its variable;

    if(dataList.size() > 0)//resizing each data object with new variable
        for(MyData x: dataList)
            x.addNew(i);
    TableColumn<MyData, Integer> newColumn = new TableColumn<>("#" + String.valueOf(++numberOfColumns));    
    newColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getCellValue(i).asObject());
    newColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<MyData, Integer>forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));

    tableView.getColumns().add(newColumn);
}
private void buttDeleteColumnAction(ActionEvent event){

}
private void buttAddRowAction(ActionEvent event){
    dataList.add(new MyData(numberOfColumns));

}
private void buttDeleteRowAction(ActionEvent event){

}

//*******************************************************************
public class MyData{ //dont forget about public because you wont get acces to properties
    private ObservableList<SimpleIntegerProperty> cellValue = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public MyData(int howManyColumns) {
        for(int i=0; i<howManyColumns; ++i)
           this.cellValue.add(new SimpleIntegerProperty(new Random().nextInt(10)));
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty getCellValue(int whichOne) {
        return cellValue.get(whichOne);
    }

    public void setCellValue(int cellValue, int whichOne) {
        this.cellValue.set(whichOne, new SimpleIntegerProperty(cellValue));
    }

    public void addNew(int numberOfNewElement){ //ads another variable for another column
        cellValue.add(new SimpleIntegerProperty(new Random().nextInt(10)));
    }
}

//*******************************************************************
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    try {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```