# JavaFX Derby TableView

Tags: dynamic, javafx, tableview

I found several solutions for writing data to tableView.

My question is: Is there any solution for writing data to a TableView in JavaFX from local Derby where we don't know how many columns and records will be and what will be the name of the attributes?

I need somekind of dynamic solution which numbers the columns and the records of a table and after generate the Table's content.

Comment: You can use the `ResultSetMetaData` to get all this information at runtime, and build the columns dynamically. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395016/how-can-i-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-javafx-8-tableview) for building the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public TableData readData(Connection conn, String dbTableName) throws SQLException {
    try (
        Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement() ;
        ResultSet resultSet = stmnt.executeQuery("select * from "+dbTableName) ) {

        ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData() ;
        List<String> colNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= meta.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            String columnName = meta.getColumnName(i);
            colNames.add(columnName);                
        }

        List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();

        while (resultSet.next()) {
            Map<String, String> row = new HashMap<>();
            for (String col : colNames) {
                row.put(col, resultSet.getString(col));
            }
            data.add(row);
        }

        return new TableData(colNames, data);
    }
}

public static class TableData {
    private final List<String> columnNames ;
    private final List<Map<String, String>> data ;

    public TableData(List<String> columnNames, List<Map<String, String>> data) {
        this.columnNames = columnNames ;
        this.data = data ;
    }

    public List<String> getColumnNames() {
        return columnNames;
    }

    public List<Map<String, String>> getData() {
        return data;
    }


}
```

Which you could use as follows:

```
TableView<Map<String, String>> table = new TableView<>();
Connection conn = ... ;
String dbTableName = ... ;

Task<TableData> loadDataTask = new Task<TableData>() {
    @Override
    public TableData call() throws Exception {
        return readData(conn, dbTableName);
    }
};
loadDataTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
    table.getColumns().clear();

    TableData tableData = loadDataTask.getValue();
    for (String columnName : tableData.getColumnNames()) {
        TableColumn<Map<String, String>, String> col = new TableColumn<>(columnName);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
            new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(cellData.getValue().get(columnName)));
        table.getColumns().add(col);
    }
    table.getItems().setAll(tableData.getData());
});

loadDataTask.setOnFailed(event -> loadDataTask.getException().printStackTrace());

Thread loadThread = new Thread(loadDataTask);
loadThread.setDaemon(true);
loadThread.start();
```

Comment: As always, your solution is great! Thank you! By the way have you got any idea how to modify this table to be editable? I mean if I would like to edit some values of the record IN the table? Thank you again for the solution above!