# Dynamic TableView using FXML

Tags: java, dynamic, tableview, javafx-8, fxml

I am new to JavaFX and I want to create dynamic table (number of rows and columns is taken from file) using FXML (SceneBuilder). I found some answers to question of creating dynamic table, but none of them using FXML.

Reason I want to use SceneBuilder is that this table will be part of more complicated scene which I don't want to program...

Can somebody provide sample code or some advice? How to use beans.property as data representation and @FXML in controller class when I don't know number of columns?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Matrix.java

```
public class Matrix {

    private final ListProperty columns;

    public Matrix() {
        this(null);
    }

    public Matrix(ObservableList columns) {
        this.columns = new SimpleListProperty(columns);
    }

    public ObservableList getColumns() {
        return (ObservableList)columns.get();
    }

    public void setcolumns(ObservableList columns) {
        this.columns.set(columns);
    }

    public ListProperty columnsProperty() {
        return columns;
    }
}
```

MainApp.java

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;
    private ObservableList<ObservableList> matrixData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public MainApp(){
        ObservableList<String> col1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        col1.add("A");
        col1.add("B");
        col1.add("C");
        ObservableList<String> col2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        col1.add("D");
        col1.add("E");
        col1.add("F");
        matrixData.add(col1);
        matrixData.add(col2);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("RuleMaker");

        initRootLayout();

        showMatrixOverview();
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the root layout.
     */
    public void initRootLayout() {
        try {
            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/RootLayout.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shows the person overview inside the root layout.
     */
    public void showMatrixOverview() {
        try {
            // Load person overview.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/MatrixOverview.fxml"));
            AnchorPane matrixOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

            // Set person overview into the center of root layout.
            rootLayout.setCenter(matrixOverview);

             MatrixOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
            controller.setMainApp(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the main stage.
     * @return
     */
    public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
        return primaryStage;
    }

    public ObservableList<ObservableList> getMatrixData() {
        return matrixData;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

MatrixOverviewController.java

```
public class MatrixOverviewController {
    @FXML
    private TableView<ObservableList> table;


    // Reference to the main application.
    private MainApp mainApp;

    /**
     * The constructor.
     * The constructor is called before the initialize() method.
     */
    public MatrixOverviewController() {
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
     * after the fxml file has been loaded.
     */
    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        for(ObservableList o : mainApp.getMatrixData()){
            new TableColumn<Matrix, String>().setCellValueFactory(cellData -> (ObservableValue<String>)cellData.getValue().getColumns());      
        }
    }

    /**
     * Is called by the main application to give a reference back to itself.
     * 
     * @param mainApp
     */
    public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
        this.mainApp = mainApp;
        table.setItems(mainApp.getMatrixData());
    }
}
```

I don't know how should MatrixOverviewController class look, how to fill it and tag it properly. This code is probably utter garbage.

Comment: What's the actual issue? You create your `TableView` in FXML and then configure it in the controller, using any of the Java techniques you said you found in other answers. Post some code showing what you've tried.

Comment: @James_D Ok, I will add some code, but I think that it is totally wrong...

Comment: Yeah, there's kind of way too much wrong with that code to know where to start - and it really can't be answered in a single question. I guess my advice would be to start by getting your types correct; i.e. don't use raw types like `ObservableList` (always `ObservableList<Something>`), and understand how the parametrized types for `TableView` and `TableColumn` work (the first type in `TableColumn` must be the same as the type for the `TableView`. You need to add the columns to the table...

Comment: I also don't really understand a couple of things in the text in the question. What does "How to use beans.property as data representation?" mean?

Comment: Yeah.. I tried to explain something I don't really understand. I was referring to Matrix.java and how to use property types correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will try to figure it out.

Comment: @James_D I made it to work thanks to your answer in other thread.

Comment: Excellent; glad it helped. Which thread was it? I can mark this question as a duplicate of that, which will help other users looking for the same information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395016/how-can-i-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-javafx-8-tableview