# Creating rows after creating custom columns

Tags: javafx, tableview, multiple-columns, rows, observablelist

I am creating a scoreboard with javafx.
My program has a table, with one column which is game id. When you press new game you can add up to 10 players. Type in the players names and press the button to add players to the table columns. I have provided pics below so you can have a clearer understanding.

[Adding Players](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP4de.png)

[After players added to columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goYdv.png)

Here is where I'm stuck. I need to add scores per game on the rows. Since I'm generating a custom number (2-10) of columns depending on the number of players. I can't use this code because I don't know how many parameter is needed for score constructor in Score Class.

Is there a way to create 3 int parameter in the score class if there are 3 players added? Or could I approach this in a different way? Another option maybe will be to add random numbers below then dynamically editing the rows to the real score, but then again the program doesn't know how many columns there are so this will be hard as well.

```
public ObservableList<Score> getScore() {
        ObservableList<Score> scores= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        scores.add(new Score(10,12,13,11,15,90));
        scores.add(new Score(100,10,29,29));
        return scores;
    }
```

Example of what I'm think how it should look:

```
Game Nr:|Bill Gates | Steve Jobs |
   1    |    80     |    10      |
   2    |    6      |    75      |
```

PS: Is there a way to sum the column and show the total score. I want the sum to be on the last row so even if I add a new row with scores the sum will appear below that row.

Codes Used to add players from textfield to column:

```
        TableColumn<Player, String> p1 = new TableColumn<>(player1.getText());
        TableColumn<Player, String> p2 = new TableColumn<>(player2.getText());
        TableColumn<Player, String> p3 = new TableColumn<>(player3.getText());
        table.getColumns().addAll(p1, p2, p3);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395016/how-can-i-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-javafx-8-tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a game class which has a game number (fixed) and represents the scores as a map from players to values:

```
public class Game {
    private final int gameNumber ;
    private final ObservableMap<String, Integer> scores 
        = FXCollections.observableHashMap();

    public Game(int gameNumber) {
        this.gameNumber = gameNumber ;
    }

    public ObservableMap<String, Integer> getScores() {
        return scores ;
    }

    public int getGameNumber() {
        return gameNumber ;
    }
}
```

If I understand the requirements correctly, when the user enters new players, you want to reset the table, which you can do with the method below:

```
private TableView<Game> scoreTable ;

// ...

private void resetTable(List<String> players) {
    scoreTable.getColumns().clear();
    scoreTable.getItems().clear();

    TableColumn<Game, Integer> gameNumCol = new TableColumn<>("Game");
    gameNumCol.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new ObservableValueBase<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer getValue() {
            return cellData.getValue().getGameNumber();
        }
    });
    scoreTable.getColumns().add(gameNumCol);

    for (String player : players) {
        TableColumn<Game, Integer> col = new TableColumn<>(player);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
            Game game = cellData.getValue();
            IntegerBinding score = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() ->
               game.getScores().getOrDefault(player, 0),
               game.getScores());
            return score.asObject() ;
        });
        // if you need editing:
        col.setOnEditCommit(e -> {
            Game game = e.getRowValue();
            Integer newScore = e.getNewValue();
            game.getScores().put(player, newScore);
        });
        scoreTable.getColumns().add(col);
    }
}
```

Then you can just add new `Game`s to the table's items list, and they will default to zero scores for each player. You can set scores with

```
game.getScores().put(player, score);
```

SSCCE at https://gist.github.com/james-d/aa51204a2e7ed16d75b7

Comment: I do not understand why you use `ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper` this way. In this case using it's superclass `SimpleIntegerProperty` would do the same. If you don't want to allow changing the value, you'd need to use [`getReadOnlyProperty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.html#getReadOnlyProperty--).

Comment: True enough. It's just consistent with the implementation of `PropertyValueFactory`, but you're correct: there's actually no benefit to it.

Comment: Updated accordingly :).

Comment: Thanks, this help a lot!