# How to manipulate data I got from textfield and populate to table column in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX, and I'm sorry if this sound stupid. I'm working on a desktop app to display data from the database. I'm using JPA Hibernate.

This is a database of contractors and contracts, by getting the startdate of  contract and contract duration from input, I want to be able to calculate the end date and display it to the table.

I created the method to calculate endDate, by the adding the number of month to the start date, but the problem is how do I display it on the Table.

Look at controller class:

```
package energiadata.controller;



public class ActiveContractTabController {

private ObservableList<ActiveContractor> dataActive = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@FXML
private VBox vBox;
@FXML
private TextField tfContractor;
@FXML
private TextField tfNatureOfContract;
@FXML
private TextField tfUser_dept;
@FXML
private TextField tfValue;
@FXML
private TextField tfValueRate;
@FXML
public DatePicker startDatePicker;
@FXML
public TextField tfContractDuration;
@FXML
private TextField tfremarks;
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> choiceBox;
@FXML
private Button addContractButton;
@FXML
private TextArea resultAreaActive;
@FXML
private TableView<ActiveContractor> activeContractTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ActiveContractor, Integer> idColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ActiveContractor, String> contractorColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ActiveContractor, String> natureOfContractColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ActiveContractor, String> user_deptColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ActiveContractor, Integer> valueNairaColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ActiveContractor, Integer> valueDollarColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ActiveContractor, LocalDate> start_dateColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ActiveContractor, LocalDate> end_dateColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ActiveContractor, String> contractTypeColumn;
@FXML
private TableColumn<ActiveContractor, String> remarksColumn;
@FXML
private Button allContractsButton;
@FXML
private Button updateButton;
@FXML
private Button deleteButton;

public void setupTableActive() {
    idColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().idAProperty().asObject());
    contractorColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().contractor());
    natureOfContractColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().natureOfContract());
    user_deptColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().user_dept());
    valueNairaColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().value().asObject());
    valueDollarColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().valueMain().asObject());
    start_dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().start_date());
    end_dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().end_date());
    contractTypeColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().contractType());
    remarksColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().remarks());
}

@FXML
void addButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    String contractor = tfContractor.getText();
    String natureOfContract = tfNatureOfContract.getText();
    String user_dept = tfUser_dept.getText();
    Integer value = Integer.parseInt(tfValue.getText());
    Integer valueRate = Integer.parseInt(tfValueRate.getText());
    LocalDate start_date = startDatePicker.getValue();
    Integer contractDuration = Integer.parseInt(tfContractDuration.getText());
    String contractType = choiceBox.getValue();
    String remarks = tfremarks.getText();

    ActiveContractor activeContractor = new ActiveContractor(contractor, natureOfContract, user_dept, value, valueRate, start_date, contractDuration, remarks, contractType);

    try {
        activeContractTable.getItems().add(activeContractor);

        DBUtil.saveActiveContractor(activeContractor);

        resultAreaActive.setText("Active Contract Added");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resultAreaActive.setText("Error adding active contract" + e);
    }

}

@FXML
void deleteActiveContractor(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    activeContractTable.getItems().remove(activeContractTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());

    DBUtil.removeActiveContractor(activeContractTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    resultAreaActive.setText(" Contractor Deleted! ");

}

@FXML
void updateActiveContractorDetails(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    ActiveContractor activeContractor = activeContractTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

    String _contractor = tfContractor.getText();
    String _natureOfContract = tfNatureOfContract.getText();
    String _user_dept = tfUser_dept.getText();
    Integer _value = Integer.parseInt(tfValue.getText());
    Integer _valueRate = Integer.parseInt(tfValueRate.getText());
    LocalDate _start_date = startDatePicker.getValue();
    Integer _contractDuration = Integer.parseInt(tfContractDuration.getText());
    String _remarks = tfremarks.getText();

    try {
        DBUtil.updateActiveContractor(activeContractor);

        activeContractTable.getItems().add(activeContractor);
        activeContractTable.toFront();

        resultAreaActive.setText(_contractor + "updated Successfully!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resultAreaActive.setText("Could not update the Database" + e);
    }
}

@FXML
void getActiveContractorList(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEntityManager();
    List<ActiveContractor> list = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM ActiveContractor a", ActiveContractor.class).getResultList();
    if (dataActive == null) {
        dataActive = FXCollections.observableArrayList(list);
    } else {
        dataActive.clear();
        dataActive.addAll(list);
    }

    activeContractTable.setItems(dataActive);
    // contractorTable.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);

    setupTableActive();

    resultAreaActive.setText(" List Display! ");

}

ActiveContractor activeContract;

public LocalDate changeEndDateProperty() {   
      LocalDate localdate = startDatePicker.getValue();
    LocalDate end_localDate = localdate.plusMonths(Long.valueOf(tfContractDuration.getText()));

    return end_localDate;
}



public Integer valueRateCal() {
    Integer valueMainDollar = Integer.parseInt(tfValue.getText())
            * Integer.parseInt(tfValueRate.getText());
    return valueMainDollar;
}

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    setupTableActive();
    choiceBox.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList("One-Off", "Running"));
}
```

}

And Entity Class: 
    package energiadata.model;

```
public class ActiveContractor implements Externalizable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private IntegerProperty idA;
private int _idA;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "id")
public final int getId() {
    if (idA == null) {
        return _idA;
    } else {
        return idA.get();
    }
}

public final void setId(int id) {
    if (this.idA == null) {
        _idA = id;
    } else {
        this.idA.set(id);
    }
}

public IntegerProperty idAProperty() {
    if (idA == null) {
        idA = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "id", _idA);
    }
    return idA;
}

private StringProperty contractor;
private String _contractor;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "contractor")
public final String getContractor() {
    if (this.contractor == null) {

        return _contractor;
    } else {
        return contractor.get();
    }
}

public final void setContractor(String contractor) {
    if (this.contractor == null) {
        _contractor = contractor;
    } else {
        this.contractor.set(contractor);
    }

}

public StringProperty contractor() {
    if (contractor == null) {
        contractor = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "contractor", _contractor);
    }
    return contractor;
}

private StringProperty natureOfContract;
private String _natureOfContract;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "natureOfContract")
public final String getNatureOfContract() {
    if (this.natureOfContract == null) {
        return _natureOfContract;
    } else {
        return natureOfContract.get();
    }
}

public final void setNatureOfContract(String natureOfContract) {
    if (this.natureOfContract == null) {
        _natureOfContract = natureOfContract;
    } else {
        this.natureOfContract.set(natureOfContract);
    }

}

public StringProperty natureOfContract() {
    if (natureOfContract == null) {
        natureOfContract = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "natureOfContract", _natureOfContract);
    }
    return natureOfContract;
}

private StringProperty user_dept;
private String _user_dept;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "user_dept")
public final String getUser_dept() {
    if (this.user_dept == null) {
        return _user_dept;
    } else {
        return user_dept.get();
    }
}

public final void setUser_dept(String user_dept) {
    if (this.user_dept == null) {
        _user_dept = user_dept;
    } else {
        this.user_dept.set(user_dept);
    }

}

public StringProperty user_dept() {
    if (user_dept == null) {
        user_dept = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "user_dept", _user_dept);
    }
    return user_dept;
}

private IntegerProperty value;
private int _value;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "value")
public final Integer getValue() {
    if (this.value == null) {
        return _value;
    } else {
        return value.get();
    }
}

public final void setValue(Integer value) {
    if (this.value == null) {
        _value = value;
    } else {
        this.value.set(value);
    }

}

public IntegerProperty value() {
    if (value == null) {
        value = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "value", _value);
    }
    return value;
}

private IntegerProperty valueMain;
private Integer _valueMain;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "valueMain")
public final Integer getValueMain() {
    if (this.valueMain == null) {
        return _valueMain;
    } else {
        return valueMain.get();
    }
}

public final void setValueMain(Integer valueMain) {
    if (this.valueMain == null) {
        _valueMain = valueMain;
    } else {
        this.value.set(valueMain);
    }

}

public IntegerProperty valueMain() {
    if (valueMain == null) {
        valueMain = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "valueMain", _valueMain);
    }
    return valueMain;
}

private IntegerProperty valueRate;
private int _valueRate;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "valueRate")
public final Integer getValueRate() {
    if (this.valueRate == null) {
        return _valueRate;
    } else {
        return valueRate.get();
    }
}

public final void setValueRate(Integer valueRate) {
    if (this.valueRate == null) {
        _valueMain = valueRate;
    } else {
        this.value.set(valueRate);
    }

}

public IntegerProperty valueRate() {
    if (valueMain == null) {
        valueMain = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "valueMain", _valueRate);
    }
    return valueRate;
}

private SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate> start_date;
private LocalDate _start_date;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "start_date")
public final LocalDate getStart_date() {
    if (this.start_date == null) {
        return _start_date;
    } else {
        return start_date.get();
    }
}

public final void setStart_date(LocalDate start_date) {
    if (this.start_date == null) {
        _start_date = start_date;
    } else {
        this.start_date.set(start_date);
    }

}

public SimpleObjectProperty start_date() {
    if (start_date == null) {
        start_date = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "start_date", _start_date);
    }
    return start_date;
}

private ObjectProperty<LocalDate> end_date;
private LocalDate _end_date;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "end_date")
public final LocalDate getEnd_date() {
    if (this.end_date == null) {
        return _end_date;
    } else {
        return end_date.get();
    }
}

public final void setEnd_date(LocalDate end_date) {
    if (this.end_date == null) {
        _end_date = end_date;
    } else {
        this.end_date.set(end_date);
    }

}

public ObjectProperty end_date() {
    if (end_date == null) {
        end_date = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "end_date", _end_date);

    }

    return end_date;
}

private IntegerProperty contractDuration;
private Integer _contractDuration;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "contractDuration")
public final Integer getContractDuration() {
    if (this.contractDuration == null) {
        return _contractDuration;
    } else {
        return contractDuration.get();
    }
}

public final void setContractDuration(Integer contractDuration) {
    if (this.contractDuration == null) {
        _contractDuration = contractDuration;
    } else {
        this.value.set(contractDuration);
    }

}

public IntegerProperty contractDuration() {
    if (contractDuration == null) {
        contractDuration = new SimpleIntegerProperty(this, "contractDuration", _contractDuration);

    }
    return contractDuration;
}

private StringProperty remarks;
private String _remarks;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "remarks")
public final String getRemarks() {
    if (this.remarks == null) {
        return _remarks;
    } else {
        return remarks.get();
    }
}

public final void setRemarks(String remarks) {
    if (this.remarks == null) {
        _remarks = remarks;
    } else {
        this.remarks.set(remarks);
    }

}

public StringProperty remarks() {
    if (remarks == null) {
        remarks = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "remarks", _remarks);
    }
    return remarks;
}

private StringProperty contractType;
private String _contractType;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "contractType")
public final String getContractType() {
    if (this.contractType == null) {
        return _contractType;
    } else {
        return contractType.get();
    }
}

public final void setContractType(String contractType) {
    if (this.contractType == null) {
        _contractType = contractType;
    } else {
        this.contractType.set(contractType);
    }

}

public StringProperty contractType() {
    if (contractType == null) {
        contractType = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "contractType", _contractType);
    }
    return contractType;
}

public ActiveContractor() {
}

public ActiveContractor(String _contractor, String _natureOfContract, String _user_dept, int _value, int _valueRate, LocalDate _start_date, Integer _contractDuration, String _remarks, String _contractType) {
    this._contractor = _contractor;
    this._natureOfContract = _natureOfContract;
    this._user_dept = _user_dept;
    this._value = _value;
    this._valueRate = _valueRate;
    this._start_date = _start_date;
    this._contractDuration = _contractDuration;
    this._remarks = _remarks;
    this._contractType = _contractType;
}

public ActiveContractor(StringProperty contractor, StringProperty natureOfContract, StringProperty user_dept, IntegerProperty value, IntegerProperty valueRate, SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate> start_date, IntegerProperty contractDuration, StringProperty remarks, StringProperty contractType) {
    this.contractor = contractor;
    this.natureOfContract = natureOfContract;
    this.user_dept = user_dept;
    this.value = value;
    this.valueRate = valueRate;
    this.start_date = start_date;
    this.contractDuration = contractDuration;
    this.remarks = remarks;
    this.contractType = contractType;
}

@Override
public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
    out.writeInt(getId());
    out.writeObject(getContractor());
    out.writeObject(getNatureOfContract());
    out.writeObject(getUser_dept());
    out.writeObject(getValue());
    out.writeObject(getValueMain());
    out.writeObject(getValueRate());
    out.writeObject(getStart_date());
    out.writeObject(getEnd_date());
    out.writeObject(getContractDuration());
    out.writeObject(getRemarks());
    out.writeObject(contractType());

}

@Override
public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    setId(in.readInt());
    setContractor((String) in.readObject());
    setNatureOfContract((String) in.readObject());
    setUser_dept((String) in.readObject());
    setValue((Integer) in.readObject());
    setValueMain((Integer) in.readObject());
    setValueRate((Integer) in.readObject());
    setStart_date((LocalDate) in.readObject());
    setEnd_date((LocalDate) in.readObject());
    setContractDuration((Integer) in.readObject());
    setRemarks((String) in.readObject());
    setContractType((String) in.readObject());

}
```

}
Since the Methods in not the Entity, I couldn't add it to the column... I've been on this for days.

My question is different from [How can I add rows and columns to a JavaFX 8 TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395016/how-can-i-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-javafx-8-tableview).

I already add columns to my tableview, check my setupTableActive() method above. What I'm trying to do is, for example, the end_dateColumn, I want to be able to get value fron DatePicker and add some months to it, then set it to the end_dateColumn. But by default, it only allows me to put Property method in the entity class there. Hope this is clear enough...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add rows and columns to a JavaFX 8 TableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395016/how-can-i-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-javafx-8-tableview)

Comment: That is not what I'm asking. Read my post again.

Comment: I still dont properly understand your question then, for better help you need to show us more code. And what method is not an Entity? Do you get an error that you can show us?

Comment: So is the `public LocalDate endDate() { ` method not working? or are you unable to add months to the value? Or are you unable to put the date in the end_dateColumn?

Comment: @sorifiend I've shown more code. I want to be able to manipulate the value I get from input(like add some value to it) and the populate it in the tableview. But it is like I can only add Entity object to the tableview. But the endDate I created is not an entity object, so that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I see a lot happening here that needs a bit of work, but lets just look at your issue and you can sort the rest out yourself. From what I can tell it looks like you dont ever pass your end_date to the activeContractTable TableView and therefore the end_date will never be added to the Table no matter how hard you try, but you can fix this quite easily by adding and adjusting several lines of code as shown below:

Note my comments starting with `//======`

In the ActiveContractTabController class addButton method:

```
@FXML
void addButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    String contractor = tfContractor.getText();
    String natureOfContract = tfNatureOfContract.getText();
    String user_dept = tfUser_dept.getText();
    Integer value = Integer.parseInt(tfValue.getText());
    Integer valueRate = Integer.parseInt(tfValueRate.getText());
    LocalDate start_date = startDatePicker.getValue();
    //====== You need to add the end date here =====//
    LocalDate end_date = changeEndDateProperty();
    Integer contractDuration = Integer.parseInt(tfContractDuration.getText());
    String contractType = choiceBox.getValue();
    String remarks = tfremarks.getText();

    //====== You need to add the end date to the line below, and modify ActiveContractor to receive the extra end_date variable =====//
    ActiveContractor activeContractor = new ActiveContractor(contractor, natureOfContract, user_dept, value, valueRate, start_date, end_date, contractDuration, remarks, contractType);
```

In the ActiveContractor class:

```
//====== You need to add the end date to the line below as one of this methods inputs so it accepts the call from ActiveContractTabController =====//
public ActiveContractor(String _contractor, String _natureOfContract, String _user_dept, int _value, int _valueRate, LocalDate _start_date, LocalDate _end_date, Integer _contractDuration, String _remarks, String _contractType) {
    this._contractor = _contractor;
    this._natureOfContract = _natureOfContract;
    this._user_dept = _user_dept;
    this._value = _value;
    this._valueRate = _valueRate;
    this._start_date = _start_date;
    //====== You need to add the end date here =====//
    this._end_date = _end_date;
    this._contractDuration = _contractDuration;
    this._remarks = _remarks;
    this._contractType = _contractType;
}


//====== You need to add the end date to the line below as one of this methods inputs so it accepts the call from ActiveContractTabController =====//
public ActiveContractor(StringProperty contractor, StringProperty natureOfContract, StringProperty user_dept, IntegerProperty value, IntegerProperty valueRate, SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate> start_date, SimpleObjectProperty<LocalDate> end_date, IntegerProperty contractDuration, StringProperty remarks, StringProperty contractType) {
    this.contractor = contractor;
    this.natureOfContract = natureOfContract;
    this.user_dept = user_dept;
    this.value = value;
    this.valueRate = valueRate;
    this.start_date = start_date;
    //====== You need to add the end date here =====//
    this.end_date = end_date;
    this.contractDuration = contractDuration;
    this.remarks = remarks;
    this.contractType = contractType;
}
```

I have not tested or checked this code, so you may need to make other adjustments for it to work as intended, but it should give you an idea.