# How to fill javafx.TableView in FXML controller?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to fill TableView with columns in controller but I don't know why my solution doesn't work.

in fxml the element I want to fill, looks like this:

```
<right>
    <TableView id="datesTableView">
    </TableView>
</right>
```

In the controller:

```
public class ProjectController implements Initializable {

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    LocalDate first = p.getStartDate(); 
    LocalDate last = p.getLastDay(); 

    List<TableColumn> list = new LinkedList<>();
    while(!first.equals(last)) {
        TableColumn tb = new TableColumn();
        tb.setGraphic(factory.getRotated(FileUtil.convertDateToString(first))); 
        list.add(tb);
        first = first.plusDays(1);
    }
    datesTableView.getColumns().setAll(list);
```

The following tableview is to contain column with dates. In the loop I am adding subsequent dates to columns and then to list. I receive error when I try to add the list of columns to datesTableView which is the last line. Rest works as I want - I tested it.

The error I receive is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ganttchart.controller.ProjectController.initialize(ProjectController.java:89)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 63 more
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException: Root cannot be null
```

Line 89 is

```
datesTableView.getColumns().setAll(list);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add rows and columns to a JavaFX 8 TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395016/how-can-i-add-rows-and-columns-to-a-javafx-8-tableview)

Comment: probably something wrong in the code/fxml you are not showing ;) please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly

Answer (score -1):

You'd need a property defined for datesTableView. Use the @FXML annotation with it.